# Python xmpp module compatible with osx

Tags: python, macos, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I'm trying to run GCM sample fromhttp://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html on osx but i'm unable to install xmpp library. On Linux installation apt-get install python-xmpp resolved case. For osx I couldn't find anything

Comment: https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=xmpp

Comment: @NedDeily Thanks, I know macports. I've tried py-xmpppy and py-xmpppy and still _import xmpp_ raises an error.

Comment: You'll need to use the appropriate MacPorts Python as well, e.g. `sudo port install py27-xmpp` then use `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: Still not providing xmpp, I've done workaround - pure setup.py but still it's strange that none of ports didn't provide proper import xmpp. It's a shame that google didn't mentioned what kid of lib they used.

Answer (score 0):

There is another repository called ActiveState PyPM
Try to download it from here:

http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

install it, and after, write on a cmd line:

pypm install xmpppy

That worked for me